# Python: SQL query not always return all values

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script which looks for values in a table named "test_table".
I want to count the occurencies of "active" or "canceled" status in this table.
If the number is below a certain value, it gives an error.

The problem is that almost 50% of the times I run this script, it returns a lower number of occurencies than the ones that are really there.
The database itself has just a few tables and this particular one has less than 1000 entries, so it's a very small DB.

```
import time
import mysql.connector as mysql
from datetime import datetime

while True:             
            
    db = mysql.connect(
        host = "xxxxx",
        user = "xxxxxxxxx",
        passwd = "sadasdasdasda",
        database = "asgsfsdfsdfsd"
    )
    
    
    try:
        sql_select_Query = "select * from test_table WHERE status in ('active', 'canceled') "
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(current_time + " , Counter = " +str(len(records)))    

    except mysql.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            logging.warning("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            logging.warning("Database does not exist")
        else:
            logging.warning(err)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
   

    time.sleep(5)
```

what could be the reason for not counting all of them?
DB problem? or python problem?

EDIT:

I tried to run the script above just for statistics.
look how inconsistent is the reading:

```
15:02:48 , Counter = 271
15:02:54 , Counter = 271
15:03:00 , Counter = 271
15:03:06 , Counter = 28
15:03:12 , Counter = 212
15:03:18 , Counter = 271
15:03:24 , Counter = 271
15:03:30 , Counter = 271
15:03:37 , Counter = 271
15:03:43 , Counter = 271
15:03:49 , Counter = 271
15:03:56 , Counter = 271
15:04:02 , Counter = 271
15:04:08 , Counter = 63
15:04:14 , Counter = 271
15:04:19 , Counter = 271
15:04:25 , Counter = 271
15:04:31 , Counter = 271
15:04:37 , Counter = 271
15:04:43 , Counter = 271
15:04:49 , Counter = 271
15:04:55 , Counter = 271
15:05:01 , Counter = 271
15:05:07 , Counter = 39
15:05:13 , Counter = 271
15:05:19 , Counter = 271
15:05:25 , Counter = 271
15:05:32 , Counter = 271
15:05:38 , Counter = 271
15:05:43 , Counter = 271
15:05:50 , Counter = 271
15:05:55 , Counter = 271
15:06:02 , Counter = 271
15:06:08 , Counter = 48
15:06:14 , Counter = 271
15:06:20 , Counter = 271
15:06:25 , Counter = 271
15:06:31 , Counter = 271
15:06:37 , Counter = 271
15:06:43 , Counter = 271
15:06:49 , Counter = 271
15:07:05 , Counter = 20
15:07:11 , Counter = 183
15:07:17 , Counter = 271
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question with the info you provided. As a rule of thumb, I would never store de facto enum values like active or cancelled as a string.

Comment: @baao there isn't anything more related to the DB in the code, it's as simple as that. regarding your sentence: how would you store them if not string?

Comment: What happens if you use `len(records)` instead of `cursor.rowcount`?

Comment: Make sure the records in the table don't have extra spaces in the `status` field.

Comment: @Val You could use `ENUM('active', 'canceled', ...)`. However, the value of `ENUM` types is fieircely debated in the industry. Some prefer to use foreign keys to a `status_values` table.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, the problem is exactly the same even if I use len(records). sometimes the count is correct, sometimes not. It's like if sometimes it loads just half of the DB. There aren't spaces in the status field.. thanks for the ENUM suggestion, even if I doubt it's the solution to the problem..

Comment: Use `print(records)` and see if you can find a pattern to the missing records. BTW, I recommend writing `WHERE status in ('active', 'canceled')`, it makes the logic easier to understand, and I think MySQL optimizes it better.

Comment: And if all you care about is the count, use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ...` rather than fetching all the records.

Comment: one more thing: I noticed just now, by using heidisql to connect to the db, that the problem persists. when I am inside the table, if I press refresh, sometimes only part of the table is loaded or items are "0". I'm doubting now it's a python issue...

Comment: @Barmar I added more tests in the original question

Comment: You are sleeping for 5 seconds and yet the time stamps vary as much as 16 seconds (from 15:06:49 to 15:07:05) to retrieve 20 rows. How would you account for that? Something is broken somewhere. You might want to dump your database, make sure you have all the rows and recreate it and reload it.

Comment: @Booboo something is broken somewhere, this is sure :) I will contact my domain provider, I'm using the db provided with my domain. thank you